# Javascript if radio button selected, additional input required

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm working on a customer survey where I ask the customer if they'd like to be contacted about their experience.  If they select yes, additional questions follow asking them their preferred method of contact & the info for the selected method.

**HTML**

```
<b>May we contact you about your experience?</b>
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="Contact" id="ContactYes" value="Yes" required />
<label for="ContactYes">Yes</label>
<input type="radio" name="Contact" id="ContactNo" value="No" />
<label for="ContactNo">No</label>

<br />
<br />

<b>Select your preferred method of contact:</b>
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="FormOfContact" id="Phone" value="Phone" />
<label for="Phone">Phone</label>
<input type="radio" name="FormOfContact" id="Email" value="Email" />
<label for="Email">Email</label>
```

Basically, what I'd like to know is how can I make 'FormOfContact' a required field ONLY when the user selects "Yes" to being contacted?

Answer (score 0):

If you create an onchange event for the radio buttons, you can check whether "yes" or "no" is selected. If "yes" is selected, add the attribute "required=true" to the second field.

```
ELEMENT.setAttribute("required",true)
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit of javascript could help.
See plunker here: http://embed.plnkr.co/k3yIf0gh03JBACSeV6yA/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script>
function onChange(required) {
  document.getElementById('Phone').required = required;
  document.getElementById('div1').style.display = required ? 'block' : 'none';
}  
</script>

<body>
    <b>May we contact you about your experience?</b>
    <br/>
        <input type="radio" name="Contact" id="ContactYes" value="Yes" required onChange='onChange(true)'/><label for="ContactYes">Yes</label>
        <input type="radio" name="Contact" id="ContactNo" value="No" onChange='onChange(false)' /><label for="ContactNo">No</label>

    <br />
    <br />
    <div id='div1' style='display:none'>
        <b>Select your preferred method of contact:</b><br/>
        <input type="radio" name="FormOfContact" id="Phone" value="Phone" /><label for="Phone">Phone</label>
        <input type="radio" name="FormOfContact" id="Email" value="Email" /><label for="Email">Email</label>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```